# How to convert Excel data with only values to google sheets by using google app script?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert excel data to google sheet by using google apps script.

The details is as follows:

- Source file: Excel(.xlsx)
- Destination: Google Spreadsheet
- env: Google Drive - Google Apps Script(on Web)
- Purpose: just import values (only) of excel into Google sheet (like copy and paste only values in Excel)

Actually, I did convert the excel to the google sheet by using apps script. However, I faced some problem. 
The problem is a specific excel formula that was made by someone and also moved into the google sheet. So Google sheet failed those values with  **"#REF"** because of this formula.

I tried to extract the data with C# from excel file that includes above formula. The result was good because I could get only values.

So I think I can also get only values of excel and then import or convert it to google sheet with google apps script on web.

Could you help me on how to convert data (only) of excel to google sheet by using the apps script?

Comment: Please update your post with the answers to the following questions. What version of Excel? What is the actual Excel formula and how is it expressed (programming language, number of cells it is used in, how many cells is it duplicated in, etc.)? What is the app script you used for conversion?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry about my limited information. My principle hope is to extract the values(only) of excel files and import a new google sheet. And also I need to do all of it on the Google Drive with Google App Script that Google provides.

Comment: What I would try is to save the Excel spreadsheet in .csv format (Comma Separated Values which is a text file) and then import the .csv file into Google spreadsheet. This will give you only values and eliminate any formulas.

Comment: As @RichardChambers said, if you just want the values you could just convert your file to csv. Although it would be nice to see the formula which is making the conversion fail.

Comment: Have you seen any article about "Excel to Google Sheet" conversion? I recommend [this one](https://www.labnol.org/code/20500-convert-microsoft-excel-xlsx-to-google-spreadsheet) for the introduction.